Does FCM have any limitations on the number of free in-app/push notifications? Can it handle 21M+ notifications/month for 7M users?
I am building a mobile application with a large user base (7 million subscribers). The app needs to send a high volume of in-app and push notifications (over 21 million per month). I'm considering using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to handle this.
My main questions are:
Free Tier Limitations: Does FCM have any restrictions on the number of notifications that can be sent for free? Are there daily or monthly limits I should be aware of?
Scalability: Can FCM reliably handle sending over 21 million notifications per month to 7 million users? Are there any performance or cost considerations I should take into account when scaling to this volume?

Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/1dbuivf/does_fcm_have_any_limitations_on_the_number_of/

firebaser here
Firebase Cloud Messaging sends between 15 and 20 million messages per second, so the volume you're describing is not a problem for the service.
The only documented limitation is around the quota of messages you can send per minute. From :

When sending messages against the FCM HTTP v1 API, each request consumes an allotted Quota Token in a given time window. This window, called a "Token Bucket", refills to full at the end of the time window. For example: the HTTP v1 API allots 600K Quota Tokens for each 1-minute Token Bucket, which refills to full at the end of each 1-minute window.

So you can send 600K messages per minute, but I recommend reading out the entire page to learn the full details.
